Print text to bluetooth printer in capacitor react
I am trying to print text to a bluetooth printer using capacitor, react, nextjs application.
So far I have tried following:
following is to list the available devices

// ScanForDevices.tsx page


import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BleClient } from '@capacitor-community/bluetooth-le';
import { BiRefresh } from 'react-icons/bi';

interface ScanForDevicesParams {
    onSelectDevice: (data: any) => void;
}

const ScanForDevices = ({ onSelectDevice }: ScanForDevicesParams) => {
    const [devices, setDevices] = useState<any>([]);

    const scanDevices = async () => {
        setDevices([]);
        try {
            await BleClient.initialize();
            await BleClient.requestLEScan({}, (device) => {
                setDevices((prevDevices: any) => [...prevDevices, device]);
            });

            setTimeout(async () => {
                await BleClient.stopLEScan();
            }, 10000);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        scanDevices();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='flex justify-between items-center m-3'>
                <span>Scanned Devices</span>
                <button className='bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600' onClick={scanDevices}>
                    <BiRefresh size={25} />
                </button>
            </div>

            <ul>
                {devices.map((device: any) => (
                    <li key={device} className='px-3 py-5 m-3 rounded bg-gray-300 shadow-md' onClick={() => onSelectDevice(device)}>
                        {device.device.name || device.localName || device.device.deviceId}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ScanForDevices;


following is to print the text to the printer.

// HandleThermalPrint.tsx file

import { BleClient } from '@capacitor-community/bluetooth-le';
import { showToast } from '@/components/toastNotification';

interface SendData {
    data: object;
    template: string;
    printerAddress: string;
}

export default async function HandleThermalPrint({ data, template, printerAddress }: SendData) {

    const receiptData = "hello";
    const uint8Array = new TextEncoder().encode(receiptData);
    const dataView = new DataView(uint8Array.buffer);

    try {
        await BleClient.initialize();

        await BleClient.connect(printerAddress);

        const printer_properties = await BleClient.getServices(printerAddress);

        let serviceUuid = "";
        let characteristicUuid = "";

        for (const service of printer_properties) {
            for (const characteristic of service.characteristics) {
                if (characteristic.properties.write || characteristic.properties.writeWithoutResponse) {
                    serviceUuid = service.uuid;
                    characteristicUuid = characteristic.uuid;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (`${serviceUuid || ""}`.length > 0 && `${characteristicUuid || ""}`.length > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (`${serviceUuid || ""}`.length > 0 && `${characteristicUuid || ""}`.length > 0) {
            await BleClient.write(
                printerAddress,
                serviceUuid,
                characteristicUuid,
                dataView
            );

            showToast({
                status: "success",
                message: "Receipt printed successfully!",
            });
        } else {
            showToast({
                status: "error",
                message: "No serviceId and characteristicUuid provided"
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
        showToast({
            status: "error",
            message: `Error printing receipt. Please try again. ${error}`,
        });
    } finally {
        //
    }


}


I am getting the list of devices and i can select any device.
But the main issue is I am not getting the my printer in the list, i think my printer doesn't support bluetooth low energy technology (BLE).
how can i overcome this?
https://bluprints.in/product/pragati-economy-2000/ this is my printer
this is their documentation: https://newsite.bluprints.in/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/Pragati-Regular-booklet-1.pdf

Please check the documentation or manual of your printer to make sure it uses BLE and how to make it discoverable.
